# how to get width and height of monitor in python glfw

Tags: java, python, opengl, glfw

I used glfw in Java a few months ago and i clearly remember

```
GLFWVidMode vidmode = GLFW.glfwGetVideoMode(GLFW.glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
GLFW.glfwSetWindowPos(window,vidmode.width()/2-width/2,vidmode.height()/2-height/2)
```

can be used to position your window in the center but when i try to do that in python in a similar way (considering that rest of the code for glfw in python is purely identical to java) it doent work becuase the object vidmode has no method height or width .... how can i recover hte width and height of my monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the size from the `size` attribute:

```py
monitor = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor()
vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(monitor)
v_width = vidmode.size.width
v_height = vidmode.size.height
```

See [glfw/glfw](https://github.com/glfw/glfw)

Comment: ya that size attribute is an extra there